# ABPersonViewController call edit from my code?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

It may not be possible to achieve but I want to make sure by asking you all.
I have customized contacts info page (looks like native contacts page with some changes)..I have edit button..now I want to call native edit functionality which is there in ABPersonViewController.

Problem for me is I don;t want to load ABPersonViewController as I am already on my own contacts view.
Let me know if it is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's probably not possible to take the "editing" from the ABPersonViewController, the editing depends on a lot on the exact elements in the ABPersonViewController. However as I see it ABPersonViewControllers editing is based on the normal functionality in UITableViews. So I think it would be pretty easy to make an implementation which resembles what you are looking for.

Check out this video : http://vimeo.com/1680510

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  The iOS address book is exposed through a Core Foundation API.  See Apple's [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) for more information.